# Ruby: Efficient way to compare two arrays of arrays

Tags: arrays, ruby, sorting

I search the most efficient way to get the difference between two arrays of arrays.
At this point I don't know if working with hash would be better.

I have two arrays of array containing one id and one datetime converted to int.

```
a = [[1, 1234],[2, 7345],[3, 12769],[4, 13456], [5, 34765]]
b = [[1, 1234],[3, 12769],[2, 7345],[5, 39875],[4, 13459]]
```

My goal is to know if the date contained in each arrays of a is superior to the date contained with the same id in b and keep the arrays that match the comparaison otherwise I would have done
something like a - b.

What is the fastest and cleanest way even with large amounts of arrays ?

The alternative way would be with hash, I don't really know what to use.

```
a = [{id: 1, date: 1234},{id: 2, date: 7345},{id: 3, date: 12769},{id: 4, date: 13456},{id: 5, date: 34765}]
b = [{id: 1, date: 1234},{id: 3, date: 12769},{id: 2, date: 7345},{id: 5, date: 39875}, {id: 4, date: 13459}]
```

What are your thoughts ?

Comment: When you say large amounts of arrays, how large? Are the arrays too big to keep in memory? If so, that complicates things a bit.

Are the two data structures relatively sorted to each other like in your example? In other words `a[i]==b[i]` will always be true? If so, that simplifies things a bit.

Comment: @PaulNikonowicz I mean array with few ten of thousands ids and dates inside, it might not be sorted like a[i]==b[i] all the time.

Comment: Well, if it all fits in memory (it sounds like it might), then we could start by sorting both arrays. 

Using a hash vs an array isn't going to make this any easier to develop, but it might make things easier to read. I think an array is fine though.

Comment: With `a` unchanged could `b` equal `[[2, 7345],[1, 1234],[3, 12769],[4, 13459], [5, 39875]]`?

Comment: @CarySwoveland Yes b could be equal to something like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is easier and better performing to have `b` be a hash. Fortunately, an array of 2-element arrays can be directly converted to hash with `.to_h` (and back to array with `.to_a`).

```
# this will make an { <id> => <date> } hash
b_hash = b.to_h
```

Now the filter step just involves a `select` over `a`, checking the associated values in `b_hash`. I use `|(id, date)|` to *destructure* the array into its individual elements:

```
result = a.select do |(id, date)|
  b_hash[id] > date
end
```

Note that you do want to keep the `.to_h` call outside the `select` loop since it's an O(N) operation.

You could do it without converting `b.to_h`, you would just need to loop through `b` for each element of `a`, taking the time complexity from O(N) to O(N^2)

Comment: I think the OP gave an example of an array of arrays vs an array of hashes. I think what you're trying to illustrate is that a Hash (no arrays at all) will perform better here.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose `a` and `b` are defined as follows.

```
a = [[1, 1235] ,[2, 7345], [3, 12760],[4, 13466], [5, 34765]]
b = [[5, 39875],[3, 12769],[2, 7345], [1, 1234],  [4, 13459]]
```

Then

```
a.select { |id,date| date > b.assoc(id).last }
  #=> [[1, 1235], [4, 13466]]
```

See [Array#assoc](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-assoc). This is not the most efficient solution but it may be fine if `a` and `b` are not too large. I posted it mainly because it uses a method that I rarely use.

Comment: What an oddly specific method. I guess you found the use case right here!

Comment: @maxpleaner, "I rarely use" probably should be "I've never used" (just as I've never used `for`). Note there is also [Array#rassoc](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-rassoc), which is even more bizarre.